# Get Value of Adjacent Cell and paste in Master Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

[image][image]Attached are 2 screenshots of the sample data files. One is the control and other is the worksheet. Might have several worksheets but all names are there in control.[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp25q.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp25q.png)I have a master Sheet called Control and several other worksheets. The control sheet looks like this
Row 3 has dates
Row 4 has the words Opening and closing. pair of opening and closing has 1 date

```
        Date 1.    Date 1. Date 2.  Date 2
       Opening.  Closing  Opening. Closing
```

`ABCD` and `EFGH` are the 2 worksheets but the number of worksheets may change everyday. In both these sheets there is a String called Closing. Adjacent value has a number which needs to go into the Control Sheet matching the Dates as well. The date is also there in the worksheet always in e4 of every worksheet and sheet name is also present in e3 of every worksheet.
What i have tried is below but am unable to proceed -

```vb
        Dim ws as Worksheet
        Dim lastrow as Long
        Dim Nextrow as Long
        Dim Range as Range
        Dim rFind as range


        For each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Control" then
        
        Set rFind = .Find(What:="Closing", Lookat:=xlwhole, MatchCase:=False, 
        SearchFormat:=False)
```

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `Adjacent value`? Sharing a screenshot about data layout is helpful.

Comment: The cell immediate to the right. So if string “closing” is found in q8, I need q9 value pls

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, mainSht As Worksheet
    Dim rFind As Range, rDate As Range, rSht As Range
    Dim iDate, arrDate, arrSht
    Dim DateCnt As Long, ShtCnt As Long
    Dim i As Long, iRow As Long, iCol As Long
    Const KEYWORD = "Closing"
    Set mainSht = Sheets("Control")
    ' Load date and sheet name
    With mainSht
        arrDate = .Range("C3", .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value
        DateCnt = UBound(arrDate, 2)
        arrSht = .Range("B5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value
        ShtCnt = UBound(arrSht)
    End With
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Control" Then
            ' Search KEYWORD
            Set rFind = ws.Cells.Find(What:=KEYWORD, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
                iDate = ws.Range("E4").Value
                ' Validate E4 is Date
                If IsDate(iDate) Then
                    iRow = 0: iCol = 0
                    ' Match date in row 3
                    For i = 1 To DateCnt
                        If arrDate(1, i) = iDate Then
                            iCol = i + 3
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next i
                    If iCol > 0 Then
                        ' Match sheet name in Column B
                        For i = 1 To ShtCnt
                            If arrSht(i, 1) = ws.Name Then
                                iRow = i + 4
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next i
                        If iRow > 0 Then
                            ' Populate Control sheet
                            mainSht.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = rFind.Offset(0, 1)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible you can explain the logic for this one please - For i = 1 To DateCnt
                        If arrDate(1, i) = iDate Then
                            iCol = i + 3
                            Exit For

Comment: So i changed the code slightly so because if the different columns. The issue am facing is for 1 date its working fine but when we change the date its not populating in the correct column in Control Sheet. In the control Sheet the dates are in S3 AND the words closing balance is in S4. In the worksheets the date is in Q3 and Sheet Name in Q2. ----With mainSht
        arrDate = .Range("S3", .Cells(19, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value
        DateCnt = UBound(arrDate, 2)
        arrSht = .Range("R5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp)).Value
        ShtCnt = UBound(arrSht)

Comment: You should not change the code if the layout of control sheet isn't changed. Using `iCol = i + 3` to get the column index of `closing`.